# Postgres heap table performance on SSD

Tags: mysql, postgresql, performance, rdbms, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I've read [Performance difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL for the same schema/queries.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41232/performance-difference-between-mysql-and-postgresql-for-the-same-schema-queries/49062#49062). *Is it still relevant with appearance of Solid State Drive?*

That article said that Postgres is better for complex queries and subquering, and worse for simple queries by ids and sequential scans.

Postgres is worse/slower for some queries due each table is a heap, means hasn't clustered index, means rows are not physically sorted on hard drive by their primary key. So if you want to read a significant portion of records (by id as I understand) from Postgres - that will lead to many random I/O and poorer performance if compare with MySQL.

***Questions:***

1. *But how about SSD? Have sequential reads got same performance for Postgres and MySQL?*
2. *Also does it make any sense to use SSD instead of HHD with RDBMs?*

### Update: related to Rick James' answer

1. *MySQL use `Plan A` and Postgres use `Plan B`, right?*
2. *`Plan A` means clustered index, right?* The table is physically sorted by `lastName + firstName`.
3. `Plan A` on HDD could perform better that `Plan B` on SSD, so Postgres + SSD is not an silver bullet. *You need to choose MySQL for quering clustered index, right?*
4. *Pls more details about which queries do you mean by I/O bound?* In my understanding `any call to database == I/O bound operation`.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key I agree with that: clustered indexes don't really buy you that much (and Oracle seems to agree on that, as they are not the default in Oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Count the disk hits."

Let's construct a simplistic table and query against it.  Then let's discuss how two database engines will perform that query.

We have a table with lastname and firstname, plus other stuff.  The table is quite big; so big that it cannot be cached in RAM.  The query needs to look up all the people with a given last name and some first initial:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
    WHERE lastname = 'James'
      AND firstname LIKE 'R%';
```

Plan A:  The table is ordered by lastname+firstname using a B+Tree.  The operation work like this:

1. Locate the first (James,R) row.  This requires drilling down the layers of a B+Tree of depth perhaps 4.  It is very likely that all non-leaf nodes in such a tree will stay cached.  But the leaf node won't be (because of the size of the atable).  Cost (so far):  0 disk hits for the non-leaf nodes, plus 1 disk hit for the leaf node.
2. Scan forward through the B+Tree.  Let's say the typical block in the tree holds 100 records.  Let's say there are 300 names that match.  Cost:  About 3 more disk hits.

Total cost:  ~4 disk hits.

Plan B:  There is an `INDEX(lastname, firstname)` to hash-pointer, which then leads to the data.

1. Traverse that index to find all the 300 matching names.  If the INDEX is something like a BTree, that is, again, ~4 disk hits.
2. For each of the 300 names, do a hash lookup in the data to get `SELECT *`.  Since the look up involves a hash, the records will be scattered around.  And, since I hypoticated that the table was too big to be cached, that is upwards of 300 disk hits to find the records.

Total cost:  Somewhere between 4 and 304; let's be generous and say 100.

Further, let's say there is 1ms of CPU for the entire query.  And let's say 10ms for HDD disk hit and 0.5ms for SDD disk hit.

```
Plan             HDD (ms)   SDD (ms)   RAM (ms, if the table were fully cached)
Plan A: B+Tree    41          3          1
Plan B: Hash    1001         51          1
```

(Side note: Indexing on UUID in any database engine is like throwing out BTree and using only Hash.)

Until SSDs become as fast as RAM, there will be a performance gap.

As your you Question 2 (Does it make sense to use SSDs):  If you are I/O-bound, then yes.  Otherwise, it may not be "cost-effective".  An RDBMS tries to cache everything, thereby eliminating I/O (for *reads*); if the data is small enough, the I/O speed does not matter.

On the other hand, *writes* are much more likely to be dependent on I/O speed.  But that is another discussion (with a similar conclusion).

Responding to question update:

1. Disclosure:  I am very familiar with MyISAM; Plan A is very close to MySQL's InnoDB.  I am very *unfamiliar* with Postgres; I do not know if Plan B relates to it.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. It depends. A `SELECT` where everything it needs is cached in ram: no I/O.  A write in a transaction with setting at maximum security: always I/O.  And there is lots of "in between".